# Save content of textarea "onkeypress" with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, store, keypress

I'm a beginner with Ajax requests and i'm stuck with this : I want to save a textarea in my database for every keypressed.

**JavaScript**

```
   $("#note_content").bind("keydown", function() {
        note(this.value)
   });

   function note(value) {
       $.ajax({
           async : false,
           type: "GET",
           url: "./ajax.php",
           data: {
             'block' : 'note', 
             'text'  : value
           },
           success: function(data) {
             $("#note_content").html(html);
           }
       });
   }
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

 function note() {
   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname="myDatabase";charset=utf8', 'root', 'password');
   $req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE note set text= ?');
   $req->execute(array($_GET['text']);

   $reponse = $bdd->('SELECT text FROM note');
   $donnees = $reponse->fetch();
   $text = $donnees; 
   return($text)
}

if(($_GET['block'] == 'note'){
    echo note();
}
?>
```

With JQuery I am listening on keypress for the textarea. When happening, it pass the key which is pressed to function `note()` which pass parameters to PHP. It saves the text in the table `note` and return the stored text.

I got error 500 (Internal server error) and i don't know what's wrong with my code.
Maybe it's about `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` which need to be `json` content-type ?

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's probably the missing semi-colon on the end of `return($text)` - turn on error reporting and it will give you some (occasionally) useful info

Comment: Side note: you want to use POST instead of GET, otherwise you will soon hit the url limit when a user starts writing his/her autobiography in the textarea.

Comment: Second side note: `onkeypress` is a very bad idea, you should debounce and save only each 5 or 10 seconds and `onblur` f.e. (there are a number of libraries available for debouncing events)

Answer (score 0):

in ajax related API where you need to make output readable by the javascript and need to make error_reporting to 0, so pure JSON output is printed and you javascript can easily read it... you can do like this...

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

 function note() {
   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname="myDatabase";charset=utf8', 'root', 'password');
   $req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE note set text= ?');
   $req->execute(array($_GET['text']);

   $reponse = $bdd->('SELECT text FROM note');
   $donnees = $reponse->fetch();
   $text = $donnees; 
   return($text)
}

if(($_GET['block'] == 'note'){
    $output = array();
    $output['status'] = true;
    $output['error'] = 'no errors';
    $output['data'] = note();
    echo json_encode($output);
}else{
    $output = array();
    $output['status'] = false;
    $output['error'] = 'block is not note';
    echo json_encode($output);
}
?>
```

in javascript you can check it like...

```
 success: function(data) {
         $("#note_content").html(data['data']);
       }
```